# Spring security j_spring_security_check call gives 404 not found error

Tags: ajax, spring, spring-security

I am trying to create a login authentication with spring security. I am receiving a 404 not found error for my login url `/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_check`. I have correctly defined my custom filter and my url in the security xml. Also I added a security filter in the web xml file. I am calling this url via an ajax request by serializing the form data. I had this code working in another project seuccessfully but now I am getting this error. What might be the cause?

This is security.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <!-- Disabled Security for Static Resources -->
    <global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" secured-annotations="enabled"/>
    <http pattern="/static/**" security="none"/>

    <beans:bean id="shaPasswordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="256"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.service.UserService"/>

    <!-- Ajax Aware Handler -->
    <beans:bean id="authEntryPoint"
                class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AjaxAwareLoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint"
                scope="singleton">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="loginFormUrl" value="/knowledge-base"/>
    </beans:bean>

    <http authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager" entry-point-ref="authEntryPoint"
          pattern="/knowledge-base/**"
          use-expressions="true" disable-url-rewriting="true">

        <custom-filter position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" ref="loginFilter"/>
        <logout logout-success-url="/knowledge-base" invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID"
                logout-url="/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_logout"/>

        <intercept-url pattern="/knowledge-base/" access="permitAll"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/knowledge-base/memory"
                       access="hasRole('ADMIN') || hasRole('MODERATOR') || hasRole('USER')"/>

        <access-denied-handler error-page="/knowledge-base/error/403"/>
        <session-management session-authentication-error-url="/knowledge-base/error/sessionExpired"/>
    </http>

    <!-- ************************** -->

    <authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="shaPasswordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="loginFilter"
                class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <beans:property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_check"/>
        <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:bean class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AuthenticationSuccessHandler"/>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:bean class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.spring.AuthenticationFailureHandler"/>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <!-- ************************** -->


</beans:beans>
```

This is web.xml file :

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Spring Web MVC Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml,
            /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>encoding</param-name>
            <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>knowledge-base</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlets/knowledge-base-dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>main</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/visual/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>knowledge-base</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/knowledge-base/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

This is my login form :

```
<form id="login-form">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Username</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="j_username" ng-model="username"
                                   placeholder="Your username">
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Password</label>
                            <input type="password" name="j_password" class="form-control" ng-model="password"
                                   placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <!--<input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="exampleCheck1">-->
                            <!--<label class="form-check-label">Check me out</label>-->
                        </div>
                        <span class="validation-message" style="display:none;">{{validationMessage}}</span>
                        <span class="success-message" style="display:none;">{{successMessage}}</span>
                        <input type="button" class="btn btn-default blue" value="Log in"
                               ng-click="login()">
                    </form>
```

And this is how I call the j_spring_security_check url via ajax :

```
$.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: 'knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_check',
                            data: jQuery("#login-form").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
                            success: function (data) {
                                window.location = "/knowledge-base/memory";
                            },
                            error: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                                if (data.status == 410) {
                                } else if (data.status == 409) {
                                } else if (data.status == 406) {
                                } else {
                                }

                                $scope.$digest();

                                printError(textStatus);
                            }
                        });
```

But I receive a 404 not found error.

[image]

UPDATE :

After solving this, I had trouble with my UserService. It does not recognize the autowired dependencies that are defined within it. I tried both using Autowired annotation directly on the variable and on the constructor separately. `knowledgbaseDao` is null in the `loadUserByUsername`. On startup, constructors of this class is called 3 times. Each creates different objects. First one is created using the default empty constructor. Other two is created using the autowired constructor and assigns `knowledgebaseDao` the correct class. When userservice is called from login page it uses the first UserService class and a null pointer exception is thrown. Here is my code :

```
@Component("userService")
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserService.class);

    private KnowledgeBaseDao knowledgeBaseDao;

    public UserService(){
        System.out.println();
    }

    @Autowired
    public UserService(KnowledgeBaseDao knowledgeBaseDao) {
        this.knowledgeBaseDao = knowledgeBaseDao;
        }

    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws AuthenticationException {
        logger.info("UserDetails Database Service : " + login);

        // check user exists in database
        User user = knowledgeBaseDao.findUserByEmail(login);
        if (user == null) {
            logger.warn("User({}) does not exist in system", login);
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("There is no user with this username.");
        }

        boolean containsLoginRole = checkLoginRole(user);

        if (!containsLoginRole) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Access denied.");
        }

        if ((user.getStatus() == null || user.getStatus() == 0)) {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User is not confirmed");
        }

        //boolean enabled = user.getStatus() == AccountStatus.ACTIVE;
        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        if (user.getLoginTryCount() != null && user.getLoginTryCount() >= 3) {
            accountNonLocked = false;
        }

        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), true, accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, this.getAuthorities(user.getRoleId()));
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Collection<Role> roleList) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (Role role : roleList) {
            authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role.getName()));
        }
        return authorities;
    }

    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities(Long roleId) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();

        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Constants.ROLE_NAME(roleId.intValue())));

        return authorities;
    }

    private boolean checkLoginRole(User user) {
        if (user.getRoleId() == 0) {
            return false;
        }

        if (user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_ADMIN
                || user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_MODERATOR
                || user.getRoleId() == Constants.ROLE_USER) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure /knowledgeBase is the root servlet context url? I think it is knowledge-base .. so in this case the correct url the make login request should be /knowledge-base/knowledgeBase/j_spring_security_check try doing a post via postman

Comment: Now I'm experiencing a problem with my UserService, it does not recognize the autorwired dependencies. I have updated my question, could you look at it?

Comment: Have you registered userdetailsservice as a bean?

Comment: In security configuration, yes.     

<beans:bean id="userService" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.service.UserService"/>. 

And I'm referencing this bean from the authentication manager.

<authentication-manager id="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userService">
            <password-encoder ref="shaPasswordEncoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

Comment: Hmm I think you need to add a datasource in your declaration

 <bean id="userDetailsServiceImpl" class="com.xxx.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl">
  <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
 </bean>
it has to be configured to your datasource, if u use sql or something

Comment: In which declaration?

Comment: in your bean  <beans:bean id="userService" class="com.gsu.knowledgebase.service.UserService"/> i think u need to add a datasource

Comment: but it does not seem to relate to datasource directly

Comment: Ok i understand now.. have you registered KnowledgeBaseDao as a bean? can u show me the code? I think thats why u getting the error

Comment: No I haven't. I've been using that class before but for security I did not.  It is defined as a @Component. Which code do you want to see.

Comment: And interestingly, 3 times this UserService is initialized with 2 autowiring the knowledgebasedao class, but the one that is not autowiring is used when authenticating.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166098/discussion-between-jun-huh-and-cuneytyvz).